# RestSharp Scrape Multiple urls with Async

Tags: c#

Check the code bellow. Here i got a list of `Url` which need to be **scraped** and fill the Html into `Html` property of `Data.Datas` global class. I already tried to do it using RestSharp `client.GetAsync` but i am not getting idea how can i to it to all list of `Url` which inside `Data.Datas`

```
public class Data
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Url { get; set; }
        public string Html { get; set; }
        public static List<Data> Datas = new List<Data>();
    }

class Program
    {

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
          

            //seeding 10 demo data
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                Data.Datas.Add(new Data
                {
                    Id = i,
                    Url = "https://www.httpbin.org",
                    Html = null,
                });
            }

            var task = Task.Run(async () =>
            {
                await DoScrapeAsync();
            });


            do
            {

            } while (!task.IsCompleted);

            Console.WriteLine("compleated");
            Console.ReadLine();


        }



        static async Task DoScrapeAsync()
        {
            var thisData = Data.Datas.FirstOrDefault();//doing firstOrDefault() which is wrong. I have to take whole list to scrape
            var client = new RestClient("http://api.scraperapi.com/?api_key=c3df2_fake_4d5e&url=" + thisData.Url + "/ip&country_code=us");
            RestRequest req = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

            //string html = client.Execute<string>(req).Content;

            var html = await client.GetAsync<string>(req);

            thisData.Html = html;
            
            Console.WriteLine(html);
        }


        }
```

Comment: If you'd spend a minute formatting the code in your question, to be more readable, you increase the chances of people actually taking a look. Espacially Indention and excess blank lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have `DoScrapeAsync` accept a single `Data` instance:

```
static async Task DoScrapeAsync(Data data)
{
    string url = $"http://api.scraperapi.com/?api_key=c3df2_fake_4d5e&url={data.Url}/ip&country_code=us";
    var client = new RestClient(url);
    RestRequest req = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

    var html = await client.GetAsync<string>(req);

    data.Html = html;
        
    Console.WriteLine(html);
}
```

Which can then be called like this in `Main`:

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    //seeding 10 demo data
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Data.Datas.Add(new Data
        {
            Id = i,
            Url = "https://www.httpbin.org",
            Html = null,
        });
    }

    await Task.WhenAll(Data.Datas.Select(DoScrapeAsync));

    Console.WriteLine("completed");
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

---

Couple of points: you need to make your `Main` `async` to be able to await each call to `DoScrapeAsync`.

Also, using `Task.Run` is completely unnecessary as this simply offloads the work to the ThreadPool and achieves nothing in your case.

Comment: Not works! I am getting error: `System.Xml.XmlException: ''doctype' is an unexpected token. The expected token is 'DOCTYPE'. Line 1, position 3.'` Please check picture here: https://ibb.co/r4dzmDJ